# AVRDude Error while working on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, embedded, avr-gcc, avrdude

I've been working on a project with ATMega32 on Eclipse, and everything was working fine, and suddenly, when I tried to build my project to download the project into the MCU, I got the following error:

```
AVRDude Error
Could not understand the output from AVRDude. 
- Either avrdude returned an error message that is not covered by AVR Eclipse Plugin
- or you have newer AVRDude version with a changed output format.
In either case check the AVRDude return message below and contact the AVR Eclipse Plugin maintainers to have this fixed.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-eclipse
Reason:
Could not find a valid Signature in the avrdude output.
```

When I checked the AVRDude output I got all the valid parts, and in the end I got this:

```
Launching: C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude -cusbasp -pm16
Output:

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude done. Thank you.

avrdude finished

Launching: C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude -cusbasp -px128a3
Output:

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude done. Thank you.

avrdude finished
```

Can someone help me and tell me how to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see AVRdude says that it cannot interact with microcontroller.
It can be bad contact between uC and usbasp or there's no power on uC. Also there's common issue - fuses corruption.
Check all that steps carefully and you should find reason for this behavior.

Comment: Thank you Sidoi for your answer, it was a bad connection between uC and USBasp.